# XMPP Groupchat Bookmark implementation

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, muc, groupchat

I have read in XMPP that in case of XMPP rooms, once a user bookmarks the room , he will automatically rejoin the room on re login. But in my case bookmark is getting stored in server as when I query it back Im able to retrieve it. But rejoining is not happening.

Also for retrieving participants list in a members only private group, members are not able to retrieve admin informations. Is it possible to retrive admin info?

Comment: Hello, can u help me? How did get the list of rooms that u created ?

Answer (score 0):

> But in my case bookmark is getting stored in server as when I query it
>   back Im able to retrieve it. But rejoining is not happening.

This is a client side feature. Your client need to support Room bookmark. It need to automatically download the list for bookmark and send join presence packet to each room.

> Also for retrieving participants list in a members only private group, members are not able to retrieve admin informations. Is it possible to retrive admin info?

I am not sure what you call "Admin information" but as described in XEP-0045:

> Member: A user who is on the "whitelist" for a members-only room or who is registered with an open room. A member has an affiliation of "member".

Being a member does not grant you any admin privileges.