# Force join a client into a room

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, smack, chatroom

I have a Xmpp application using `smack api 4.1.6` and I'm trying to force join a client without invitation.

Now, I've tried a scenario where I setup a listener and invite the client back when he leaves. It works, but that's not what I want.

I need to  force rejoin the client to the room without any invite.

Now I thought that I can like make the room bookmarked to the client but that's need to be done on the client side...

Is this possible ?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force joining a user in MUC means whenever a user is invited to a room, it automatically becomes part of the room (invite packet is intercepted on server and user is made participant of the room) and user starts receiving room messages.

If this is the desired behavior, then it requires modifications/tweaks in Openfire code (Customizations as per business needs).

Comment: Yeah, that's the extreme solution, I thought I'll just make bookmark the room for the user when he joins it the first-time. Is this possible? Cause I've seen that's available in ejabberd

Comment: Room bookmarking is client side feature as mentioned by @mickaël-rémond : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366454/xmpp-groupchat-bookmark-implementation and also mentioned in it's XEP: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html. Also take a look at this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045381/joining-xmpp-muc-room-without-invite-ejabberd. Ejabberd is providing MUC Subscriptions extension which is their own implementation, not available in Openfire.